# How to extract innerText of "Who was your first employer? into Excel from the given HTML

Tags: html, vba

```html
<div class="ContainerFieldControlHoriz" style="width: 400px;">
    <label title="Who was your first employer?" id="dnn_ctr1854_ChallengeQuestion_ChallengeQuestionCmnTextBox_ControlLabel">Who was your first employer?</label>
</div>
```

My code was

```vb
Set htmlsecurityquestion = htmldoc.getElementById("dnn_ctr1854_ChallengeQuestion_ChallengeQuestionCmnTextBox_ControlLabel")
Range("A1").Value = htmlsecurityquestion.innerText
```

but it is not working

Comment: What is `htmldoc`?

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful. What exactly is the output? An exception, blank value, some unexpected value?

Comment: I had solution on this. Thank you lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You access this value through attributes collection, not through `innerText`. Your second line should be:

```
Range("A1").Value = htmlsecurityquestion.Attributes["title"].Value;
```

Comment: That text is in the label's inner text as well.